# Tkinter Canvas: Itemconfig failed update color

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I've to change the color of the rectangle created with the Canvas item.
I've looked at other questions but I didn't find an answer to my problem.

I am recording a microphone using a USB Sound card. Once the record is started I want to put a RED light and, once it is finished, back it to green.

Here's the code:

main.py:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from GUI import Demo1

def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Demo1(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

GUI.py:

```py
class Demo1:
  def __init__(self, master):
        #Set geometry and title
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("DAQ - Sound Pressure Level")
        self.master.geometry("480x320")


        # Canvas zone
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master,width=40,height=20,background='white')
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=3)
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.grid(row=0,column=3)
        self.rect1 = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,40,20, fill="green")
        #canvas.bind(func=changecolor(canvas))



        #set buttons
        self.quitbutton = tk.Button(self.master, text = 'Quit', width = 10, command = self.close_windows)
        self.quitbutton.grid(column=1,row=0)
        self.startbutton = tk.Button(self.master, text = 'Start', width = 10, command = lambda: self.startacquisition())
        self.startbutton.grid(column=0,row=0)
        #self.zerobutton = tk.Button(self.master,text = 'Zero', width = 10, command = lambda: self.zerocalibration())
        #self.zerobutton.grid(column=2,row=0)
        #self.livebutton = tk.Button(self.master,text="Live/Stop", command=lambda: self.gui_handler, bg="red", fg="white")
        #self.livebutton.grid(column=2,row=0)


  def startacquisition(self):
        chunk = 8192  # Record in chunks 
        print("Changing rect color to red")
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.rect1,fill='red')
        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio
        [....recording stuff...]
        [...preparing plot...]
        plt.show()
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.rect1,fill='green')
```

So when I press the START button it calls startacquisition(self) function. What happend is that the color doesn't upgrade until I close all the plot.

Why?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need to add `self.master.update_idletasks()` before you open the interaface to `PyAudio`

Comment: Thank You it worked!

Do you know why PyAudio block all GUI instances?

Comment: tkinter has been made to run on a single main thread. It does not intuitively support multithreading/multiprocessing (however, both of these can be achieved in a certain way - check `Queue`). So, running another thread blocks the GUI and hence, there is no update

Comment: @FrainBr33z3: _"So, running another thread blocks the GU"_ - that's not a correct statement. Running _another_ thread won't block. Running a blocking function in the _current_ thread will block.